# gsettings command not affecting settings

Tags: command-line, notification, dconf, gsettings

I was trying to write a script that would enable and disable Do Not Disturb. As such, I was using the gsettings command to enable and disable notifications

I used these two commands:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.notifications show-banners true
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.notifications show-banners false
```

However, when actually executing these commands and testing them with `notify-send`, they did not change anything at all. When I edited the flags manually using `dconf-editor`, however, the notifications were successfully enabled and disabled. Why isn't gsettings working, and is there an alternative?

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04.

Thanks!

Comment: Can't reproduce this. For me, your gsettings commands work perfectly. When setting to "false", do not disturb symbol (the bell with a stroke through it) appears, and messages do not anymore pop up (though, obviously, they still can be seen when opening the  notifications pane). Do you see any error message when executing these commands?

Comment: @vanadium I don't see an error message, the command just goes through without an issue and the prompt for the next line appears, just without any effect. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will help you?

Try exporting DISPLAY variable first
`export DISPLAY=:0`
Then make sure you run the commands as your user and not as root.